# Closet door minimums

Tags: doors, closet

Is there a code for the minimum width of a closet door? I've always assumed it was 24 inches. Or is it determined by the square footage of the closet?

Comment: I have a hall closet with a 12" door.  Not sure there are code requirements for a closet, but could be wrong.  You need a location for code questions.

Answer (score 1):

The Code only stipulates the size of one door in a residence. It requires one egress door that...

- has a 32” clear opening with the door in the 90 degree position (which requires a 36” wide door)
- is located at a exterior entrance into the residence opening into a public way or open side yard that opens to a public way
- does not open into a garage or carport
- is a minimum of 78” high measured from top of threshold to bottom of stop
- is side-hinged (no sliding doors allowed)

See 2017 ICC R311.1 and R311.2.

The only other requirement is for sleeping room egress windows, but that’s not your question.

Answer (score 0):

If a closet isn't intended to be occupied bodily by humans it's essentially a cabinet. There are no restrictions on access to such spaces.